# How to do a LIKE query in SQLite (in Javascript) whilst passing in the search term as a parameter

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I am using React Native and am querying a SQLite database.

I wish to perform a like query, specifying the search term as a parameter.

The below works fine with the ? notation.

```
SELECT * from People WHERE Name = ?
```

This does not work or any similar variation I've tried:

```
SELECT * from People WHERE Name LIKE '%?%'
```

Anyone know how to do this properly please? Please no interpolations or suggestions open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do string concatenation in SQLite:

```
SELECT * from People WHERE Name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```

Another option is to concatenate the percent marks with the parameter in your javascript code before passing it to the query, so you can then do:

```
SELECT * from People WHERE Name LIKE ?
```

Comment: Awesome. Could not find that information easily. Many thanks, I'll accept the answer when they'll allow me.

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer enough, this gave me a massive headache in javascript!