# Javascript/sqlite3 SELECT LIKE not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite, select, get, sql-like

I want to do a select to search a table's column with a keyword and match any string that contains the keyword. The keyword is given by the user by the url. This code below works and searches the table's column but matches the EXACT keyword.
When I try to use the % to match any string in the column that contains the keyword I get a "SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range" error.

```
   app.get('/searchBook/:title',function(req,res){
    var title1=JSON.stringify(req.params.title);
    console.log(title1);
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('books');
    db.all('SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title LIKE ?',[title1] ,(err, row) => {
            if (err) {
            return  console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log(row);
            res.send(row);
    });
```

});

for example

'SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title LIKE "%?%"' , [title1]

gives

SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range

I have tried different syntax but nothing seems to work.
If anyone can help it would be appreciated

Comment: I'm researching this right now, but just as an fyi you shouldn't need to quote or escape your string substitutions per the sqlite documentation as seen in issue https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/999

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a LIKE query in SQLite (in Javascript) whilst passing in the search term as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686415/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-sqlite-in-javascript-whilst-passing-in-the-search-te)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Shawn although I thought it would this still doesn't work somehow...